# What article should I use for "air conditioning"?

Tags: articles, zero-article

Which sentences are correct?

1. We didn't have air conditioning.
2. We didn't have the air conditioning.
3. We had no air conditioning.

Comment: Could you add a little context? All 3 sentences are grammatically correct in themselves. 1 & 3 have essentially the same meaning; 2 has a different meaning so which one you want to use depends on exactly what you're trying to say.

Comment: I just wanted to say I was hot (because we didn't... etc.)

Comment: In that case Derek's answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 or 3. There is no definite article because you are not talking about a specific air conditioner system

Comment: Although if you change "air conditioning" to "air conditioner", it's 2 or 3 that are correct.

Comment: Without any context in the question you can't say that for sure, although the odds are pretty high that you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

"Air conditioning" is a process, or abstract noun.  Grammatically, it is similar to other abstract nouns such as "peace", "love", and "justice".  Abstract nouns always take the zero article, as in your examples #1 and #3 (both of which are correct).

To change the abstract "air conditioning" noun into a concrete noun, you would say "air conditioner", which is the physical machine as opposed to the process of having the air be conditioned.

> We don't have air conditioning. {zero article}

> We don't have ***an*** air conditioner.